# Is a 17 year old considered an adult to go out whenever they want? what does the law says?

Tags: teen

My 17 year old daughter took a uber with the credit card I got for her yesterday,  I did not give her permission to go to Houston to visit her bf, and she still went without respecting my decision as parent, what do I so with this girl? do 17 years old are they considered adults to do whatever they want?

Sue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too localized and regarding a legal issue, which is specifically listed as [off-topic in the help center](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However, I did provide an answer because the state in question (Texas) has an extremely high population.

Answer (score 3):

In your state, you are legally responsible for the care and well-being of your daughter [until the age of 18](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/CP/htm/CP.129.htm), and have legal control over them.

> CIVIL PRACTICE AND REMEDIES CODE
>
> TITLE 6. MISCELLANEOUS PROVISIONS
>
> CHAPTER 129. AGE OF MAJORITY
>
> Sec. 129.001.  AGE OF MAJORITY.  **The age of majority in this state is 18 years.**

However, the [age of consent in Texas](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/SOTWDocs/PE/htm/PE.21.htm), in which it is not considered a crime to engage in consenting sexual intercourse is 17.

> PENAL CODE
>
> TITLE 5. OFFENSES AGAINST THE PERSON
>
> CHAPTER 21. SEXUAL OFFENSES
> ...
> Sec. 21.11.  INDECENCY WITH A CHILD.  (a)  A person commits an offense if, with a child **younger than 17 years of age**, whether the child is of the same or opposite sex, the person:

And according to [local reports](http://www.star-telegram.com/opinion/editorials/article3851392.html), a child of 17 years that commits a crime will be tried as an adult.

---

Based on this information:

You are *allowed* to control your daughter, or tell her what to do, in the eyes of the law. You are legally allowed to prevent her from going to places, if you so choose. This knowledge will not make her obey you, so I highly recommend asking another question regarding how to set and enforce expectations with your near-adult child.

---

As an aside, I would immediately revoke her credit card privileges if she's using it in a way you don't agree with.

Comment: Revoking the credit card is probably _the_ way to deal with this, irrespective of the law.